# Passing SQL to Crystal Report

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, ado.net, crystal-reports

I was just wondering how to pass SQL to crystal report. Right now I am only able to load a premade report onto my crystal report viewer. Now, I want to be able to put in parameters for building my reports. Here's some code...

```
    private void btn_InventoryReport_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument inventoryReport = new ReportDocument();
        inventoryReport.Load("C:\\Users\\Wilson Kao\\documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\Wincent Warehouse Management Studios\\Wincent Warehouse Management Studios\\InventoryReport.rpt");
        inventoryReport.Refresh();
        crv_Report.ReportSource = inventoryReport;
        crv_Report.Refresh();
    }
```

Right now, I want to be able to add SQL to filter out the report, something like this

```
da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM InventoryView WHERE vid = @vid", cs);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@vid", OleDbType.Integer).Value = vid;
//Make Report Based on this SQL
```

I tried this : http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-sql-query.htm

but it said i'm missing an assembly or something like that (prob a 64/32 bit incompatibility) but hopefully theres something else I can do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Looked into the bug and it said that I actually needed to move some of the dlls into something called dotnet1 folder (it wasnt there I had to create it myself). After that I had to modify app.config and it worked. awesome

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/7625571/74585 I didn't have to create dotnet1, just add useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" to <startup> in app.config

Answer (score 1):

That sample code link specifies the following:

> You have to include CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine in your C#
>   Source Code.

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
```

This means that in your project's references you have to have the CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine assembly which you need to import manually. E.g. right click on References and select Add Reference then either choose the assembly from the list or navigate to it on disk.

Comment: Hi, I'm adding a reference and I saw a few crystal reports ones but I cant find the one i'm looking for (more like not too sure which one to find). I included these two references before already though, so should I already have them?

Comment: Your question's a little vague here. But you should see `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine` in your project references. Do you?

Comment: when i add reference and i'm at the project tab, I don't see anything if thats what you are talking about. if not can you direct me where to go?

Comment: What is the project tab? Do you mean the project menu in the main menu?

Comment: when i click add reference... it gives me a few tabs to find my references from. some include Project, .NET, COM, browse... etc I'm trying to add a reference but not sure which one, and if i browse for it i'm not sure which one i should add

Comment: Don't worry about adding a wrong one. If it's wrong it will simply not be used. Do you see CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine in the .NET list? If not, search your hard drive for a DLL named CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

Comment: hmmm, I couldn't find it in my hard drive. Should I download it somewhere? I thoguht it should be there if I downloaded crystal

Comment: I would suggest finding a Crystal Reports demo project, loading and then examining it. That might provide some clues. Look for a sample at CodeProject.