# Very Odd situation with CrystalReport and/or Visual studio 2010 I don't know maybe .Net Framework

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports

I faced a very odd problem It seems very funny looks like some stuffs having a fun with me.
I'm using Crystal-Report Version 13.0.2000.0 and Visual Studio 2010. Number of days ago I got a error related with my Crystal-Report, that was :

> Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

After googling I found [solution](http://www.spyriadis.net/2010/06/crystal-reports-framework-4-crdb_adoplus-dll/), Then I added the following code to app.config file and It worked well, I had no error, no exception.

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime Version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework, Version=v4.0" />
</startup>
```

Today when I wanted to use same solution in my other project it showed the message that I should download .NetFrwamework 4.0 and It causes project to not run. I thought I missed something in configuration so I went to look exactly what configurations I did in previous project. Interesting point is here when I opened the project it shows me same message to download .NetFramework 4.0, while It worked very well number of days ago and I don't have any problem with that. But now .... .

I don't know what is the problem.
Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: So that was the solution for a project you had that used Crystal Reports.  Is the new project you are working on also using Crystal Reports, or do you just want it to use the .Net Framework 4.0?  If your new project isn't for Crystal Reports, you can probably remove that tag.  Also, Have you tried installing the .Net Framework 4.0?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I almost have this problem in all my projects which used Crystal-Report. I'm using Crystal-Report in both projects, as I said before it worked well in first project, but after number of days it prompts me to download .Net 4.0. In fact I've already installed .Net 4.0.

Comment: Which you have or haven't done?  Do you have .Net 4 installed on the machine you're running your program on?

Comment: dear Merlyn I'm using VS 2010 It already install .net 4.0

Comment: Yes I understand that.  Ever done tech support before ;)?  Try *installing* it manually, and see if your problem goes away.  Even further, try uninstalling it and reinstalling it. If the installer runs successfully and all the bits are there (and not broken somehow), this probably shouldn't be happening...

Comment: But I don't have this problem before ?!! What is your idea ?

Comment: My idea is that your install either wasn't as successful as it claimed to be before, some of the bits were later broken, or your hardware is bad.  I can't tell you for sure, I'm just giving you high level suggestions that seem in line with the problem you are experiencing.  I know this isn't a for-sure answer, which is why I'm leaving it as comments.

Comment: Thank you Merlyn, I'm trying to install it again.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I somehow skimmed over these words "In fact I've already installed .Net 4.0".  Tho my suggestion remains the same - try a re-install, or a removal + reinstall :)

Comment: Problem solved dear Merlyn. have look at answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After spent many hours, I solved my problem, I don't have any idea how ?!! but It doesn't throw any exception anymore.
Things I've done :

1. I delete app.config.
2. I changed framework to 3.5 then compile it.
3. Delete all related files with project in **AppData/Local/Temp/** folder (Windows 7).
4. I changed it back to 4.0 (It generated app.config) then compile it, It automatically added following code:

   ```
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime Version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework, Version=v4.0" />
    </startup>
   ```

I ran my application without any error and exception. I don't know what was the problem but by doing these steps I fixed my issues.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Out of those, the temp folder sounds like the most likely culprit.  I didn't realize VS stored anything there, tho...

Comment: I only had to add useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" for it to work for me. Sometimes I think programming is 90% chanting magic spells, where you must say the spells in the right order or it won't work, and these are secret little phrases passed down through the ages.

Answer (score 1):

Just one thing, maybe useful for someone: for use Crystal Reports in VS 2010, you have to use Framewok 4.0 (not Framewok 4.0 Client Profile)

Answer (score -2):

You can create a folder called "dotnet1" in C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86 and copy the dll crdb_adoplus.dll in it. this solution worked for me.